# Keep initial variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `(initW)` which takes the initial width of some divs(`wrps`).

There is a side panel collapse-expand event.

On collapse, the main (center) div (`.p_ext_width`) becomes wider. I use its new width value to also set the width of the wrapper divs (`wrps`).

Then on side panel expand - I want them (wrps) to go back to their initial value (`initW`).

However, this variable (`initW`) is now overwritten by the new value (extended width).

How can I keep the original variable value?

---

```
function expand_collapse() {
    out=document.querySelector('.p_ext_width')  
    wrps=document.getElementsByClassName('page_wrapper');

    var initW=window.getComputedStyle(wrps[0], null).getPropertyValue("width"); //get width before expanding
    console.log(initW);
    initW1=initW

    if (x.className!="collapseme") {
        //......
        function functionOne(x) {
        var W=window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("width"); 
//get width after expanding
            for (e=0;e<wrps.length;e++){
                wrps[e].style.width=W;
                }
            }
        function functionTwo(var1, callback) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            callback(var1);
            }, 500);
        }
        functionTwo(out, functionOne);
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (e=0;e<wrps.length;e++){
            wrps[e].style.width=initW; //set back to initial width 
            console.log("new: " + initW1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create another variable and store the original value in that before doing any calculations?

Comment: Won't that get overwritten too by the new value? (see above  initW1). Tried it and it doesnt work...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Depends where you define it. Keep it outside of this function and only set it before you expand the side panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here problem is variable scope and you need to use **initW** as global variable and get the width in expanded state.

```
//get the original width when in expended. 
var initW = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('page_wrapper')[0], null).getPropertyValue("width");

function expand_collapse() {
    out=document.querySelector('.p_ext_width')  
    wrps=document.getElementsByClassName('page_wrapper');

    if (x.className!="collapseme") {
        //......
        function functionOne(x) {
        var W=window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("width"); 
//get width after expanding
            for (e=0;e<wrps.length;e++){
                wrps[e].style.width=W;
                }
            }
        function functionTwo(var1, callback) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function() {
            callback(var1);
            }, 500);
        }
        functionTwo(out, functionOne);
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (e=0;e<wrps.length;e++){
            wrps[e].style.width=initW; //set back to initial width 
        }
    }
}
```

In your case when **expand_collapse** called to restore original widths, you are finding collapsed **wrps divs widths** and assigning same widths back to wrps. Instead you should assign original widths of wrps divs in expanded state.

Comment: thanks, had some more trouble but the scope solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I will just take a different approach. If I need this kind of thing then at first time I will search for an custom attribute (which I will create) may be named as `iniw` for the required DOM. Then for each time I will search for the attribute `iniw`, and if it is set then I will use that value as initial value of that DOM, calculate the initial value at that moment and store that value in the mentioned attribute. Here initial value means that state which you will consider as initial, it may be anything. It's just an approach, if you need code then please explain a bit what your present code is trying to do and provide html snippet also

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes sense, I will try it too!